# Displaying better error than TypeException when doing JSON.dump on Python

Tags: python

When Python `json.dump` fails to serialise value, it does not tell what was the invalid key or where it was located. This makes `json.dump` useless when trying to locate data errors in large JSON objects.

Is it possible to improve `json.dump` `TypeError` error messages?

Answer (score 0):

One can pre-validate the data before passing it to `json.dump`. `json.dump` encoder itself does not pass data locatin information around, making it hard to use it for the task.

Here is a Python code that

- Raises nested custom exceptions to locate any keys with bad values
- Contains some useful checks and patterns for common Python libraries which might be pitfalls on naive use os `json.dump()`

Call `validate_nested_state_dict()` before passing the data to `json.dump`.

```py
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
from enum import Enum
from types import NoneType
from typing import Any

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class BadStateData(Exception):
    """Having something we do not support in the state."""


#: Types we know we can safely pass to JSON serialisation
ALLOWED_VALUE_TYPES = (
    dict,
    list,
    float,
    int,
    str,
    NoneType,
    Enum,  # Supported by dadtaclasses_json
    datetime.datetime,  # Supported by dadtaclasses_json
    Decimal,  # Supported by dadtaclasses_json
)

#: We especially do not want to see these in serialisation.
#: We need to do negative test, because Pandas types to some base class
#: magic.
BAD_VALUE_TYPES = (
    np.float32,
    pd.Timedelta,
    pd.Timestamp,
)

def validate_state_value(name: str | int, val: Any):
    if not isinstance(val, ALLOWED_VALUE_TYPES):
        raise BadStateData(f"Bad value {name}: {val} ({type(val)}")

    if isinstance(val, BAD_VALUE_TYPES):
        raise BadStateData(f"Bad value {name}: {val} ({type(val)}")


def walk(name, val):
    """Raise hierarchical exceptions to locate the bad key-value pair in nested data."""
    try:
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            for k, v in val.items():
                walk(k, v)
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            for idx, val in enumerate(val):
                walk(idx, val)
        else:
            validate_state_value(name, val)
    except BadStateData as e:
        raise BadStateData(f"Key {name} contained bad value") from e


def validate_nested_state_dict(d: dict | list | object):
    walk("state", d)
```